# How to turn off Overflow Check in VBA for MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am writting a CRC8 function in VBA which results in error: **Overflow** !

Since I cannot fix it and there are no sample code solutions on how to fix the overflow error with left shifting, I`d like to try and **turn it off** to see the result I get.

I cannot find it in options.

Comment: Change `As Integer` to `As Long`.

Answer (score 4):

> I cannot find it in options.

This is because **it is a runtime error, not an "option."**

Most likely a cause of an Overflow error is trying to slick a number that's too huge for the data type.

`Byte` type is for 0-255. `Integer` type can hold numbers up to 32,767. `Long` data type can hold numbers up to 2,147,483,647 so it's probably better suitable for your specific case.

Adjust your variables types accordingly.

Generally, VBA converts all `Integers` to `Long` these days so it's a better practice to dim your variables as `Long` by default.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/1048539) is an excellent writup as to why you should use them as `Long.`

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you left shift a Byte without overflowing:

```
Dim abyte as Byte
abyte = &H81 '10000001

'To shift left, you multiply by 2, BUT because the msb is 1, multiplying by 2 gives you an Overflow.
'To fix that, you first mask off the leftmost bit, THEN multiply by 2...

'abyte is                              10000001
'And it with the mask &H7F         And 01111111
'which results in                    = 00000001
'multiplied by 2 is               *2 = 00000010

abyte = (&H7F And abyte) * 2
```

Comment: It's a bit more complicated for Integer/Long because they are signed, but it's still possible.

Answer (score -4):

Use:

```
On Error Resume Next ' Disable Error Handler
  .. do the calculation ..
  If Err Then 
     ' Handle Error
  End If
On Error Goto 0   ' Activate Error Handler
```

Comment: This won't allow OP to evaluate an expression which raises an error. This simply ignores the error and proceeds to the next line of syntax.

Comment: gosh... that's a terrible suggestion