# Is it possible to allow Integer Overflow in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, integer-overflow

Pretty simple, but I couldn't find anything by Googling. An example of what I want to happen:

```
Function myFunc()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    a = 20000
    b = 15000
    c = a + b

    myFunc = c
End Function
```

I want myFunc() to return -30536 instead of throwing an overflow exception. I know I could write a function that does that, but I've written a bunch of code for a project with the assumption that overflow was allowed, so I'm hoping there's a quick fix.

EDIT: I don't need help coming up with a function that solves the overflow issue with type conversions. I have one already; I just want to avoid changing hundreds of addition and subtraction operations. I'm also bit frustrated that VBA seems to go out of its way to disable overflow functionality--it should let the user decide if they want to use it or not.

Comment: Why don't you use a Long type instead?

Comment: I'm translating some code from C that relies heavily on overflow for angle calculations. It stores angles as 2 byte integers.

Comment: Duplicate of [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659256/how-to-turn-off-overflow-check-in-vba-for-ms-access) pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing `MyFunc` to do the math as Long, and test for integer "overflow" and adjust

```
Function MyFunc(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    Dim sum As Long
    Const Mask As Integer = -1

    sum = CLng(a) + CLng(b)
    If sum > 32767 Then
        sum = sum - 65536
    ElseIf sum < -32768 Then
        sum = sum + 65536
    End If
    MyFunc = sum
End Function
```

Test with

```
Sub zx()
    Debug.Print MyFunc(20000, 15000)

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I ended up doing, with separate functions for addition and subtraction. Not what I was hoping for, but at least it works.

Comment: You could get away with only one function, by negating a parameter, eg `a-b` = `MuFunc(a, -b)`

Comment: Yes, for that edge case

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent `Integer` overflow in your Excel VBA code, you may use the custom `Function` to perform the `Integer` to `Long` type casting like shown below:

```
Sub TestIntegerConversion()
    Debug.Print myFuncLong(20000, 15000)
End Sub

Function myFuncLong(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Long
    myFuncLong = CLng(a) + CLng(b)
End Function
```

or without using custom Function in a simple form like this:

```
Sub PreventOverflow()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    a = 20000
    b = 15000

    Debug.Print CLng(a) + CLng(b)
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you may write your own custom function, which should implement that "overflow math" (you have somehow to specify using plain math notation how to get the number -30536 from 35000) and return the result either as `Long`, or `String`. Possible implementation is shown below (note: Overflow exception number is 6)

```
Sub OverflowCustomMath()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Long
    a = 20000
    b = 15000

On Error GoTo Err:
    Debug.Print a + b
Err:
    If (Err.Number = 6) Then
        'apply your custom overflow math, as for e.g.
        Debug.Print CLng(a) + CLng(b)
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Misses the point.  From OP _I want myFunc() to return **-30536**_

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks for your comment: please see the extended answer. Best regards,

Comment: The error handling is intriguing but is it tied to the function itself? I would want this to work for all modules.

Comment: You can add the Overflow Error handling to any Function or Sub (I guess this is what you mean by "all modules"). You can, for example, create a Global Function and place it in a Code Module to make it universally accessible from any Worksheet module, etc. Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Use typical VBA error handler but tests for your case.

```
            Option Explicit

            Sub test()
                MsgBox myFunc
            End Sub

            Function myFunc()
            On Error GoTo Local_err
                Dim a As Integer
                Dim b As Integer
                Dim c As Integer

                a = 20000
                b = 15000
                c = a + b

                myFunc = c
Local_exit:
                Exit Function
Local_err:
                If Err = 6 Then
                    myFunc = -30536
                Else
                    MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
                    '  myFunc = whatever error value to return
                End If
                Resume Local_exit
            End Function
```